# No longer able to create Facebook Page Tab App

Tags: facebook

I used to create custom page tabs following this procedure laid down by Facebook https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/ and everything worked well till last few months. But suddenly all my page tab apps went into sandbox mode and I am not able to create new page tab apps.

I can create new apps but when I try to add page tab URLs to the Page Tab section, it throws me this error

> Error
>
> There was a problem saving your changes. Please try again later.

Is it happening because of some change at Facebook Side or am I missing something?

Can someone point me to a fix.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it's a temporary glitch that happens with Facebook at random times, sometimes it will clear itself in an hour or more sometimes even days as far as I know, it is currently working for me so I guess just wait and see if it resolves itself.

Comment: Thanks @Malcolm for the feedback. Actually I am getting the same error for 2 months now so I thought Facebook must have added some additional settings to create page tab app which I am not aware of.

Comment: 2 months, that is way too long for it not to be working, can I have the app ID and I will see if I can add it as a tab to one of my pages and see if I get the same error, try to narrow it down, and maybe file a bug @Keshav

Comment: I think I have figured it out. I changed my app hosting domain and tried a new domain which resolved the problem. So I think it's something to do with the domain we were hosting our apps. Now I am able to save my page tab details with a new domain. Thanks